# How do you match text and make tab delimited table in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file called `test.txt`. I want to make a table out of this text file. I am new in python, so I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out.

test.txt

```
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001.fastq
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
73764
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001.fastq
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
78640
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_VF_1_CAACTA_L003_R1_001.fastq
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
26267
```

Code I tried:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'bbduk_trimmed')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT')
pattern3 = re.compile(r'Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC:')

l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        if pattern1.search(i):
            a = re.sub('\n','',i)
            l1.append(a)
        elif pattern2.search(i):
            a = re.sub('\n','',i)
            l2.append(a)
        elif pattern3.search(i):
            a = re.sub('Query:','',i)
            b = re.sub('\n','',a)
            l3.append(b)

output = zip(l1,l2,l3)

print (output)
```

Result I want:

```
FileName    Seq_132582_1    Seq_483974_49238
bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001.fastq    0   73764
bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001.fastq    0   78640
bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_VF_1_CAACTA_L003_R1_001.fastq    0   26267
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:
You could try it as a single expression.

```
text = open("test.txt",'r').read()

results = re.findall(r'(bbduk_trimmed.*.fastq)\nSeq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: \n(\d)\nSeq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: \n(\d*)',text)
```

This gives the below output
[image: Output]

You can then convert the result into a Dataframe if needed.

```
pd.DataFrame(results)
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the `text`? Do you just input the test.txt there?

Comment: thank, but I am still getting thiss error:`/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like objec`

Comment: Can you check type(text) . It should be a string since open("test.txt",'r').read() will read the entire text file as a string.

Comment: `python grab_text_to_column.py 
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`

Comment: Can you please double check if you are using text = open("test.txt",'r').read()? Because the class is TextIOWrapper for me if I just use text = open("test.txt",'r')

Comment: Thanks. It works now. One last request though- how do you set actual colnames instead of 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: You could use this to change the column name pd.DataFrame(results,columns=['FileName','Seq_132582_1','Seq_483974_49238'])

Comment: That give me : `<class 'str'>
  ...
0 ...
1 ...
2 ...

[3 rows x 3 columns]
`